# Applescript: How to target the 'page' property of a linked file in InDesign

Tags: applescript, adobe-indesign

I've been making an applescript to help me with one of the more mundane processes at work - going through our publication after it has gone to press, collating the filenames of each image used in the mag and on what page it was used.

So far I've been able to cobble together a good working script - it combines all of the individual indesign documents into one doc, it fires in some blank pages to make up for the ad pages I don't need the originals of, and it outputs the resulting list to a txt file.

But one thing has eluded me so far: **how the hell do I target the piece of data relating to the page that a linked file sits on in the indesign document?** I can find references to targeting pretty much every other detail - name, size, file type etc - but never any reference to the syntax needed to target the page it is used on. to give you an example of the things i **can** target, here you go:

```
tell application "Adobe InDesign CC 2019"
    tell document 1
        set docName to name of it
        set linkNameList to name of links
        set linkSizeList to size of links
        set linkTypeList to link type of links
    end tell
end tell
```

I've tried:

```
set linkPagelist to page of links

set linkPagelist to page number of links
```

...and half a dozen other variations, but it always come back as an error. Does anyone know how to call it? Or if there's a document listing the inDesign terms that can be used? Its driving me loopy...

All the best,
Ed

Comment: I only ever use JavaScript to do scripting in InDesign, but in JS, you would need to target the *parent* of the link, which should give you the graphic and from that you can the then target the *parentPage* (of the graphic). So it should be something like `set linkPage to parent page of parent of links`.

Comment: Hey @mdomino that's really helpful. i just tried this and it didn't give me an error, so i think you've put me on the right track. Gonna sift through what it's given me this morning and see if i can sift it all down into something useful...

Comment: To obtain the page number of the 1st link with AppleScript use: `set pageNumberOfLink1 to name of parent page of parent of link 1` _(Note: change the `link 1` part to `link 2` to get the page number for the second link, and so on ...)_. Or, if you want the page numbers of all links as a list use: `set pageNumberOfAllLinks to name of parent page of parent of links`. However, If it's the reference to each page you want (not the page numbers) then use; `set pageRefForLink1 to parent page of parent of link 1`,  or to get all as a list use: `set pageRefForAllLinks to parent page of parent of links`

Comment: Thanks @RobC. Blimey. It appears there's a reason that the page property isn't as easy to call - its opened up a ridiculous can of worms in this script. I was expecting them to be nice simple page ids like 01, 02, etc, but that's not the case. I think this is a bridge too far for what I'm trying to do. Without the page number i can still do what I want to achieve at 90% efficiency.I think if I had longer to fiddle i might try it, but not this time. Again, thank you both...

Comment: nit: Just thought `set docName to name of it` looks funny, I think you could write it as `set docName to its name`